# Touched Boot Sector 0

Tags: boot, grub

The installer does not honor disk install target ... it sort of installed where I asked but then during Grub creation decided to muck around the primary disk boot sector.

really not sure why that would even need to be touched?

Can I get someone to verify if this
is the case and fix that?  LinuxMint installs and runs fine on my iMac ... I am just glad the main disk was encryted.

Thx/Sx

Answer (score 0):

been 7 days ... must not be an important question.

therefore I have decided not to utilize elementary os -- going forward I evaluate other candidates for use on live MacOS targets.

bye